# Upload and Auto Resize an Image according to a max size (byte)

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

I have already uploaded the image from a form and I can resize according a value and a level of quality.
But I want to Auto resize an image according to a max size(byte).
So,

```
IF (IMAGE_UPLOADED_SIZE > MAX_SIZE)
{
   WHILE(IMAGE_UPLOADED_SIZE > MAX_SIZE)
   {
     // MAIN CALCULTATIONS
     imagecreatetruecolor(); // CREATION NEW RESIZED IMAGE
     imagecopyresampled(); // COMPOSE THE NEW IMAGE
     IMAGE_UPLOADED_SIZE = getNewSize();
   }
}
```

The loop works but it becomes wrong because **I have to get the new SIZE of the new resized image generated** from "imagecreatetruecolor()" that with a print_r() command return RESOURCE#[id].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that would be breaking this code is these: IMAGE_UPLOADED_SIZE and MAX_SIZE. Are those supposed to be variables like $image_size and $max_image_size? Or have you declared them constants with define? See here for what that is: [PHP manual - Define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

If they are variables then all you just need to tweak the code. If they are constants your approach will not work the way it is coded. you can not just change the value of a constant like you did in the While loop. See the link above. Here is the code tweaked with variables:

**NOTE TO READERS:** This code is cut down and is missing parameters that normally should be a part of the functions being run in the loop. See the examples that explain it further in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php).

```
 while ($image_upload_size > $max_size){
    imagecreatetruecolor(); 
    imagecopyresampled(); 
    // Removed $getNewSize() what was that? Your own function?
    $image_upload_size = getimagesize('IMAGE NAME/PATH HERE');
    // Now you have the value of the new size, no resource ID issue, but its temporary
    // This while loop is about to run again and wipe it with another new value
    // ADD CODE HERE to do what you need with the new image size
 }
```

Comment: They're variables. However, the original image, when it's going to upload, it's controlled by this while loop that calls the function resize() while the image's resized according to the size. The point's that when the new resized image is created with the cmds "imagecreatetruecolor()" and "imagecopyresampled()" the image becomes a resource. getimagesize('tmp_name') works but it doesn't upload the values, they are always the original values. I print the same variables (width, height, size) of the original picture. Indeed, the cmds already mentioned don't work with a resource!

Comment: Well I do not recommend this solution but a simple work around is to save the new image (resource) temporarily. Before the getimagesize() save it and then pass in the file location. Now you have new numbers. The downside is that is a heavy load to put on a server, constantly rewriting the temporary file. Why is this in a while loop anyway? You know what the max size should be, just go right to it. [Take a look at this amazing code](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) and you'll see what I mean. I feel your reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I've already thought about that way, but it isn't good for performance, so I decided to close this strange idea. Thank you however :)